# Event when go back from external url

Tags: next.js

How to call function when go back from external page?
I'm using Next JS 12.

When I click the browser's back button, I see the cached page and the function does not call

```
const MyTest = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    
    // my function
    
  }, [router]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          window.location.assign("https://www.google.com");
        }}
      >
        Navigate page
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do so using the [poststate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event)

```
useEffect(() => {
  const myFunction = () => {
    // Your function logic here
    console.log('Function called when returning from external page');
  };

  // Attach the event listener to the window's popstate event
  window.addEventListener('popstate', myFunction);

  // Remove the event listener when the component unmounts
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('popstate', myFunction);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you, But i tried this code. I see cached page only. My func is not calling